# How do I change the default file association in ES file Explorer?

Tags: file-management, default-applications

When I click on a `.bin` file in ES file Explorer, the default action is to move it to the recycle bin. How can I stop this behavior?

- I am on a Samsung S4 running Lollipop, TouchWiz ROM.
- I have looked in Settings -> More -> Default Applications. This shows 2 options only  for 'Home' and 'Messages'.
- I have installed the default app manager and there is nothing that relates to `.bin` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no file type association settings under Android so it's not Samsung's fault. ES File Explorer doesn't have an option to set a default file association but you can have the same result if you do the following.

1. Long click the item (file) you wanna open it will create a check list with the file selected.
2. Click on the three dots at the right bottom of the screen.
3. Choose `open as` then select what type of file is your `.bin` file (text,music,image,video or others). ES File Explorer will prompt a list of available apps that can open the file you wanna open, choosing other will prompt all apps that accept `intent` of any type of file. In that list choose the app that can open your bin file.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to fostandy's answer: From the three dots menu, click on "Clear Defaults" and that default app you wish to change from will no longer be the default, so you'll once again get the menu with the apps you can choose from. Of course, from that menu, you'll know how to set the new default.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for mkv files on an android tv
I have found that if you click on the gear for ES file explorer Settings then you can click on the "Cleanup settings" -> "Clear defaults"
and this fixed the issue for me (i.e. from tham moment when  click on mkv files I was again prompted to choose which app to use as I desired)
BTW: this is done for all the filetype associations at once - it seems you cannot reset the association of just the .bin files